# backed up into chain link fence- how to fix the marks on car

Tags: chevrolet, malibu, paint-scratches

I just backed up into a chain link fence with my new black malibu. Any suggestions on how to get the marks off car? Is it best to bring it somewhere

Comment: Are they just scuffs or deep scratches?

Comment: Post a pic if you can. It will help a lot. But usually the damage is such that it will have to be buffed and possibly have a new coat of clear lacquer applied.

Comment: Is this on a soft bumper skin, or on a painted panel? As @JuannStrauss suggested, a picture is worth a thousand words.